# Azuon with Wineskin on MacOS 10.13?

Tags: wine

This question concerns a [travel tool](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104037/azuon-with-wineskin-on-macos-10-13), but it may find some knowledge here.

tl;dr - Anyone using Azuon on the latest MacOS?

For more than a year, I have been using the Windows app [Azuon](http://Azuon.com) on MacOS using [Wineskin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php).  They have complicated porting instructions in a video, but when I first got it, they had an already wrapped executable.  This executable successfully updated itself several times, and when it failed (once), the MSI was successful in installing the new one.

But I updated MacOS to 10.13, and the wrapped app will not launch.  Wineskin/Winery still run, but will not run the Azuon MSI to install.

I suspect that the much older video instructions will not work, but if I can't find someone who has succeeded, I guess I'll have to try them.

UPDATE: In response to comments, I disabled Gatekeeper.  After a reboot, after attempting to launch, the following immediately appears in the system log:

```
Oct 21 21:46:30 MBP-WWG com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Oct 21 21:46:32 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Oct 21 21:46:32 MBP-WWG nfcd[552]: objc[552]: Class NFPeerPaymentTransferRequest is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NearField.framework/Versions/A/NearField (0x7fffb044da00) and /usr/libexec/nfcd (0x109fa1698). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct 21 21:46:32 MBP-WWG nfcd[552]: objc[552]: Class NFPeerPaymentRequest is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NearField.framework/Versions/A/NearField (0x7fffb044d2d0) and /usr/libexec/nfcd (0x109fa1878). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct 21 21:46:32 MBP-WWG nfcd[552]: objc[552]: Class NFPeerPaymentEnrollmentRequest is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NearField.framework/Versions/A/NearField (0x7fffb044d280) and /usr/libexec/nfcd (0x109fa1968). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct 21 21:46:32 MBP-WWG nfcd[552]: objc[552]: Class NFPeerPaymentResponse is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NearField.framework/Versions/A/NearField (0x7fffb044d2f8) and /usr/libexec/nfcd (0x109fa1cd8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct 21 21:46:32 MBP-WWG nfcd[552]: objc[552]: Class NFPeerPaymentSessionInterface is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NearField.framework/Versions/A/NearField (0x7fffb044d320) and /usr/libexec/nfcd (0x109fa1da0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct 21 21:46:32 MBP-WWG nfcd[552]: objc[552]: Class NFReaderSessionInternalInterface is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NearField.framework/Versions/A/NearField (0x7fffb044d348) and /usr/libexec/nfcd (0x109fa1e40). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct 21 21:46:32 MBP-WWG nfcd[552]: objc[552]: Class NFPeerPaymentEnrollmentResponse is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NearField.framework/Versions/A/NearField (0x7fffb044d2a8) and /usr/libexec/nfcd (0x109fa1e68). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Oct 21 21:46:41 MBP-WWG gamed[546]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[mach_recv] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
Oct 21 21:47:13 MBP-WWG com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501): com.apple.iBooksX.CacheDelete (lint): _AbandonCoalition is only available to Application services.
Oct 21 21:47:13 MBP-WWG com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.235): com.apple.pluginkit.pkd (lint): Service sets EnableTransactions=false and EnablePressuredExit=true, which makes no sense. Enabling Transactions.
Oct 21 21:47:13 MBP-WWG com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Oct 21 21:47:14 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Oct 21 21:47:14 MBP-WWG com.apple.MediaLibraryService[561]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[mach_recv] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
```

A subsequent attempt triggers

```
Oct 21 21:47:34 MBP-WWG WineskinLauncher[569]: ERROR, wrapper was re-run with no recognized command line options while already running.  This is a useless operation and ignored.
```

although 'ps -ef' shows NO process that seems to be related to Wineskin.

Comment: Why not just deploy a VM (Virtualbox or Parallels) with a full installation of Windows and run it natively there?

Comment: I don't have space for a full installation of Windows, and probably not for a "bare minimum."  Also, my Windows 7 disk is on the other side of the Atlantic, and I wouldn't touch Windows 8 or 10 if they were free (I've already used both a little).

Comment: Try codeweavers versions of wine they package in a different way so might work

Comment: are you disabling Gatekeeper to run it the first time  ?  sudo spctl --master-disable

Comment: Did Gatekeeper change in 10.13, or Apple *^%#+* once again change settings without permission?  As I said, it worked until the O.S. Update, and Winery still works.

Comment: Well did you ? I have just been through this with a half a dozen users of a wine wraper I manage that upgraded if that doesnt work I will give you the settings to ajust in wineskin

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying.  I have no memory of changing Gatekeeper fifteen months and two MacOS versions ago when I ran Azuon for the first time.  I certainly did not change anything other than the O.S. itself when I upgraded to 10.13.  Does it matter now?  If so, then "the first time" threw me off, because when it didn't work was not the first time.  Does Wineskin require different settings on MacOS 10.13 than on 10.12?

Comment: Although I am not super-thrilled with Gatekeeper, it seems a little daring to disable it for everything just so one app can run.

Comment: just disable it to run the app the first time then enable it back its the only way in high seirra to get install apps from anyone or what ever term thay use for non MAS apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. control klick the app, show package contents, 2. run wine skin app , 3. select advanced,  4. select screen options,-- uncheck everything except Decorate windows leave automatic checked. 5. next in options at the top  disable anything there related to focus and XQuarts
   [image: Azuon High sierra]

Comment: Will try later today.  I was thinking earlier it might be a change in X11 or Quartz

Comment: This appears to resolve the issue.  I can't do a full test because my subscription ran out while it was broken.  But it does launch, attempt to log in, and then tell me I need to buy another three months.  Thanks!

Comment: My subscription was not expired—somehow they switched the prefs to a different account.  But .... Sigh.  Crashes because it wants dot-net 4.5, which Winery refuses to install because "2.0 is already installed."  But according to the checklist, no dot-net is installed.  Tried forcemono, and again it won't launch.