# Can Wineskin work with Catalina?

Tags: wine, macos

I reviewed my [previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302879/azuon-with-wineskin-on-macos-10-13), and I think the differences with Catalina merit a separate question.

A double-click or a menu→open on vanilla wineskin or a wineskin-wrapped Windows app has no visible effect (except for showing the icon in the recent items part of the dock).

I verified that the settings in the accepted answer there are still set.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered.  One person claims to have gotten it to work but it wasn't easy. The previous question is here : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373851/how-to-get-wine-working-on-catalina

Comment: It works with the latest crossover engine if you turn off SIP.

Comment: Hmmm.  Turning off SIP is not sufficiently convenient.  I’ll have to study that 373851.

Comment: That is about wine, which is only part of wineskin.  But it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unofficial update of wineskin. It works on Catalina. You can find it here - https://github.com/Gcenx/WineskinServer