# Wine or Wineskin on Ventura

Tags: mac, homebrew, wine, windows

Everything I can find for Wine or Wineskin is either long untouched or **appears** to be maintained but says "up to 10.15"

A possible exception is the one installed by brew, which doesn't say what versions it will work on.  I did find the brew version suggested for Ventura, but that was on reddit—not exactly a high-quality source.  (Particularly suspect since it also suggests the apparently obsolete Wineskin as an alternative.)

I prefer Wineskin for the ability to have self-contained "wrappers" but a simple Wine that works is OK.  Any pointer to a version of either ***known to work on Ventura***?

UPDATE: I just learned about PlayOnMac which also uses Wine.  But where I heard about it called it a "free program from Apple."  It is not from Apple, which makes me a bit suspicious about whether it is "safe" to install.

Comment: All the questions here I've found so far are pre-Ventura.  Most on wineskin are pre-2013.

Comment: I have paid out for CrossOver IGoogling gives  Wineskin is now https://github.com/Gcenx/WineskinServer updates are occuring but no releases for 2 years

Comment: re PlayOnMac the website it comes from says nothing like your quote https://www.playonmac.com/en/ - where did you see that quote remebering most things on internet are not correct

Comment: Not the "website it comes from."  I said "where I heard about it."  And since I have a Facebook account, I'm well aware not only that things on internet require lots of salt but also that the internet is full of criminals.  Traceroute to playonmac.com had dozens of hops with no data.  The last hop with data was in France.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: three places where it is **not** known to work on Ventura…

I re-downloaded a Wineskin-wrapped app that I deleted [when it failed in 2017](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302879/azuon-with-wineskin-on-macos-10-13).  Don't know when/if they updated it, but it still doesn't work now.

Next I decided to take a chance on the reddit advice:

```
brew install --formula gcenx/wine/winetricks\
brew install --cask --no-quarantine gcenx/wine/wine-crossover\
```

That creates `/Applications/Wine.app` which when launched opens a Terminal with a modified path.  Trying to use `wine` there complains that `wine64` is not in the path.  But `find … -print | grep -i wine64` shows that it **is** located in the second item on $path.

I **may** try PlayOnMac after I make sure I've removed all traces of the `brew` attempt.

Reluctant to pay $74 US to run a single app I've done without for five years.

There's also Winebottler, but the latest "development" version identifies it as for Mojave.

Comment: gcenx says "CodeWeavers locks support to macOS High Sierra" so I think I'll drop the whole idea until the next time I have a whim to run a Windows app.

Comment: What does CodeWeavers locks support to macOS High Sierra mean - and CodeWeavers does support Ventura even on Apple Silicon

Comment: Not sure what it means.  Maybe even an outdated reference.  Although it looks like that file is only two months since its last edit.  But for now, the purchase price is not justified for my low-priority whim.

Comment: Why did you add back slashes at the end? It will escape line separator, won't it?

Comment: I don't recall doing that.  Maybe I should try again and make sure they aren't there.  Possible they were on reddit and not in the commands I executed.